# Printer Spooler, AddPrinterDriverEx function in c#

Tags: c#, printing, driver

Googled a lot but returned empty hand..

I would like to know if anyone used AddPrinterDriver or AddPrinterDriverEx API using winspool.drv in c#.

Please provide me the code that does initialising and using this API Call.

Urgent..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working on this same issue for some time, and have something to start with, though I am still running into issues.  I believe my real issue now is creating the list of dependent files properly.  Perhaps you know how to fill in these blanks for me?

Thanks,
Stephen

```
    private const uint APD_COPY_NEW_FILES = 0x00000008;
    private const uint APD_COPY_ALL_FILES = 0x00000004;

    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool AddPrinterDriverExW([In, Optional, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pName, uint Level, [In] IntPtr pPrinter, uint Flags);

    public static void InstallPrinterDriver2(string configFile, string dataFile, string[] dependentFiles, string driverPath, string driverName, string helpFile = null,      string monitorName = null, string defaultDataType = "RAW", bool is32Bit = false)
    {
        DRIVER_INFO_3 di3 = new DRIVER_INFO_3();
        di3.cVersion = 0x03;
        di3.pConfigFile = configFile;
        di3.pDataFile = dataFile;
        di3.pDependentFiles = string.Join(",", dependentFiles);
        di3.pDriverPath = driverPath;
        di3.pEnvironment = is32Bit ? @"Windows NT x86" : @"Windows x64";
        di3.pHelpFile = helpFile;
        di3.pMonitorName = monitorName;
        di3.pName = driverName;
        di3.pDefaultDataType = defaultDataType;

        IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DRIVER_INFO_3)));
        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(di3, intPtr, false);
            if (!AddPrinterDriverExW(null, 3, intPtr, APD_COPY_NEW_FILES))
            {
                int w32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(w32Error);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (IntPtr.Zero != intPtr) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intPtr);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct DRIVER_INFO_3
    {
        public uint cVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pName; // QMS 810
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pEnvironment; // Win32 x86
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pDriverPath; // c:\drivers\pscript.dll
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pDataFile; // c:\drivers\QMS810.PPD
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pConfigFile; // c:\drivers\PSCRPTUI.DLL
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pHelpFile; // c:\drivers\PSCRPTUI.HLP
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pDependentFiles; // PSCRIPT.DLL\0QMS810.PPD\0PSCRIPTUI.DLL\0PSCRIPTUI.HLP\0PSTEST.TXT\0\0
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pMonitorName; // "PJL monitor"
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string pDefaultDataType; // "EMF"
    }
```